# psycopg for python 3? Unable to find vcvarsall.bat error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psycopg

I'm trying to install psycopg on my computer; I have Python3.5 and PostgreSQL9.5.3 installed. I get the error `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat error` when typing `python setup.py build` on cmd. Having read some answers, it appeared to me, that the 3rd python's version is what might have caused the problem. What way should I approach it?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) helped. Downloaded Python 3.5 release.